# UISlider use for different purpose

Tags: xcode, swift

Is it possible to use the UISlider in a different way then just for audio volume adjustment? I am thinking of creating a button so that when you press it you hear a sound. Now, if the user changes the slider to value 0.3 a different sound can be played, same thing with if the slider value is 0.6. Or does anyone have any other idea how to make something happen like that. The slider would just indicate the level of intensity the sound is played (each different value has a different audio file).

I'd appreciate any advice.

Or would a Stepper be a better way to go?

Comment: How would you go about that?

Comment: Use value changed event and connect to an @IBAction and pass the slider to it.

Comment: so there would be an if statement in the IBAction say if smaller then and greater then.. How would I set that up, have been trying myself, but my swift isn't that good yet :)